# Checking the First and the Last characters of the given String - Issues with conditional logic

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'm working on the following problem from [CodingBat](https://codingbat.com/prob/p151940)

> **withoutX**
>
> Given a string, if the first or last chars are `'x'`, return the string
> without those `'x'` chars, and otherwise return the string unchanged.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> withoutX("xHix") → "Hi"
> withoutX("xHi") → "Hi"
> withoutX("Hxix") → "Hxi"
> ```

I am still getting the last char of `'x'` in my code when it has an x in the first and last index. I tried it several different ways but still getting the same result. What am I missing?

So currently my tests are not passing when the *first* & *last* chars are `'x'`. It's supposed to remove the `'x'` at the `0` and last index when the conditions are met, but only removes the first 'x' at index `0` (not the last).

```
public String withoutX(String str) {
  if(str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(0) == 'x'){
     return str.substring(1,str.length());
  }
  if(str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'x'){
    return str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
  }
  return str;
}
```

I also tried it this way as well and get those tests to pass but here I get a `StringIndexOutofBoundsException`:

```
string index out of range: -1 (line:3)
```

I failed to find out the reason of this exception.

```
public String withoutX(String str) {
  if(str.length() > 0 && str.substring(0).startsWith("x") && 
  str.substring(str.length()-1).endsWith("x")){
    return str.substring(1,str.length()-1);
  }
  
  if(str.length() > 0 && str.substring(0).startsWith("x")){
    return str.substring(1,str.length());
  }
  if(str.length() > 0 && str.substring(str.length()-1).endsWith("x")){
    return str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
  }

  return str;
}
```

Any explanations for these issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## Mistakes explained

Your first attempt fails because the first condition would match two cases: when either the stating character or both and the stating the ending characters are equal to `x`. But it checks only the first case and immediately returns, which causes incorrect results.

```
if(str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(0) == 'x'){
   return str.substring(1,str.length());
}
```

The second attempt looks better.

You've omitted the case when the given string contains only a single character, and this character is `x`. Then condition below would be evaluated to `true`:

```
if(str.length() > 0 && str.substring(0).startsWith("x") && 
   str.substring(str.length() - 1).endsWith("x")) {

   return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
}
```

And in this case `substring(1, str.length() - 1)` means `substring(1, 0)` because length in `1`, which triggers an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exactly as expected according to documentation of the [`String.substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)):

> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` – if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex`
> is larger than the `length` of this String object, or `beginIndex` is
> **larger than** `endIndex`.

Also note that `str.substring(0).startsWith("x")` is equivalent of `str.startsWith("x")`, generating substring is redundant. Similarly, `str.substring(str.length() - 1).endsWith("x")` does exactly the same as `str.endsWith("x")`.

## Valid Solution

Basically, you need to address four cases:

- The stating and the ending characters are equal to `x`, the result should be `str.substring(1, str.length() - 1)`.
- Only the stating character is equal to `x`, the expected result would be `str.substring(1)`.
- Only the last character is equal to `x`, the result would be `str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)`.
- If the given string is doesn't contain `x` (it also imply that it could be empty), return it without changes.

We can simply apply these conditions in the order list above:

```
public String withoutX(String str) {
    
    if (str.startsWith("x") && str.endsWith("x") && str.length() != 1) return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    if (str.startsWith("x")) return str.substring(1);
    if (str.endsWith("x")) return str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    
    return str;
}
```

*This solution passes all test cases on Coding Bat.*

It also can be done with fewer conditions by eliminating the leading `x` and then trailing `x`. But it would potentially require generating the substring twice, which is less performant than the first approach.

```
public String withoutX(String str) {

    if (str.startsWith("x")) str = str.substring(1);

    if (str.endsWith("x")) str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

    return str;
}
```

*This solution also passes all test cases on Coding Bat.*